# FoldLeft but preserve original data structure

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I have an iterable that is generated by reading lines from a file. As I read the lines, I want to perform some filtering operations, but I also want to compute some metadata about the operation for logging. The source files are relatively large, so I would like to do this in a single scan of the data.

Toy example:

```
def getStrings(lst: Traversable[String]): Traversable[String] = {
  val someStrings = lst.filter(_.length >= 6)
  val stringCount = someStrings.foldLeft(0)((accum, line) => accum + 1)
  println(stringCount)
  someStrings
}
```

This example has the necessary functionality, but it performs two passes over the data structure: one to filter, and one to reduce. What I want to accomplish is some kind of "foldLeft" operation that computes a running tally, but also returns the original data structure. The idea being something like:

```
def getStrings(lst: Traversable[String]): Traversable[String] = {
  val strings = lst.filter(_.length >= 6).smoothOperator(0)((accum, line) => {
    if (line.isLast) {
      println(accum)
    } else {
      accum + 1
    }
  })

  strings
}
```

Ideally, the application of `smoothOperator` would parallelize nicely just like any other map operation and would add to the accumulator as data goes through it, thus minimizing the number of iterations over the data structure.

Is this possible?

Comment: @Bergi thanks for the note - I mean `someStrings`

Comment: Yes, you [can](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/custom-collection-operations.html) but, IMHO, it is extremely complicated. My advice would be to stick with concrete data structures instead, for me almost all of the collections traits are failed transactions, which are unusable on 90% of the time. - And for not doing multiple traversals, consider using a **lazy** datastructure.

Comment: I am implementing a solution right now, but I would like to always return a Traversable of type IndexedSeq. Is that acceptable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need is IMHO isomorphic to running foldLeft but on something that does several folds at once:

```
def doubleFoldLeft[A, B, C](traversable: Traversable[A], firstZero: B, secondZero: C)(
  firstFold: (B, A) => B
)(
  secondFold: (C, A) => C
): (B, C) = traversable.foldLeft(firstZero -> secondZero) {
  case ((b, c), a) =>
    firstFold(b, a) -> secondFold(c, a)
}
```

what you are asking exactly though, would require building it kind of dynamically, so that you would turn:

```
def zipWithFoldLeftUntilElement[A, B](
  traversable: Traversable[A],
  zero: B
)(fold: (B, A) => B): Traversable[(A, B)] = ...
```

with that you would still end up using fold at the end:

```
zipWithFoldLeftUntilElement[(myTraversable.filter(...), zero) {
  ...
}.foldLeft(anotherZero) { case ((a, b), c) =>
  ... // do sth with a and c
  b -> c
} // (B, C) - tuple of 2 fold results
```

Long story short, if you want to consume stream once, but compute several things in parallel... just compute more than one thing in a `.foldLeft`. If your logic is more complicated than that... I  would consider using reactive streams like Akka Streams or FS2. If the logic is **really** messed up, I would try [Akka Streams graphs](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/stream-graphs.html).

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution

```
object GetStringsTest extends App{

  def getStringsOriginal(lst: Traversable[String]): Traversable[String] = {
    val someStrings = lst.filter(_.length >= 6)
    val stringCount = someStrings.foldLeft(0)((accum, line) => accum + 1)
    println(stringCount)
    someStrings
  }

  def getStringsOnePass(lst: Traversable[String]): Traversable[String] = {
    val folded = lst.foldRight((IndexedSeq[String](), 0)){ (e, acc) =>
      if (e.length >= 6) (e +: acc._1, acc._2 + 1)
      else acc
    }
    println(folded._2)
    folded._1
  }

  val myList = List("hi", "defenestration", "supercilious", "football", "tea")
  println(getStringsOriginal(myList))
  println(getStringsOnePass(myList))
}
```

I used foldRight just in case you want to swap out IndexedSeq with List. If you are building up a List, you need to use foldRight instead of foldLeft.

My solution returns a sequence of the correct type, but it may be of a different type than the input Traversable. The output will always be of type IndexedSeq[String]. If the input is of type List[String], the output will be of a different type.

Answer (score 1):

```
  // with immutable List
  def foldAndFilter1[A, M](orig: Iterable[A])(p: A => Boolean)(mEmpty: M)(mf: (M, A) => M): (M, Iterable[A]) =
    orig.foldLeft((mEmpty, List.empty[A])) { case ((meta, filtered), item) =>
      (mf(meta, item), if (p(item)) item::filtered else filtered)
    } match { case (meta, list) => (meta, list.reverse) }

  // with mutable ListBuffer
  def foldAndFilter2[A, M](orig: Iterable[A])(p: A => Boolean)(mEmpty: M)(mf: (M, A) => M): (M, Iterable[A]) =
    orig.foldLeft((mEmpty, ListBuffer.empty[A])) { case ((meta, filtered), item) =>
      (mf(meta, item), if (p(item)) filtered:+item else filtered)
    }

  val rs1: (Int, Iterable[Int]) = foldAndFilter1(1 to 10 toList)(n => n%2 == 0)(0)((m, _) => m+1)
  val rs2: (Int, Iterable[Int]) = foldAndFilter2(1 to 10 toList)(n => n%2 == 0)(0)((m, _) => m+1)
```

`foldRight` doesn't make any sense because can be used only on `IndexedSeq`, and effective parallelization can be achieved only on `IndexedSeq` to provide fast split operation

also can be expressed via `Cats`, but you need to have a Monoid for your M type

```
  import cats.{Applicative, Monoid, Traverse}
  import cats.syntax.applicative._
  def foldAndFilter3[F[_]: Traverse: Applicative, A, M](orig: F[A])(p: A => Boolean)(mf: (M, A) => M)(implicit fam: Monoid[F[A]], mm: Monoid[M]): (M, F[A]) =
    Traverse[F].foldLeft(orig, (mm.empty, fam.empty)) { case ((meta, filtered), item) =>
      (mf(meta, item), if (p(item)) fam.combine(filtered, item.pure[F]) else filtered )
    }

  import cats.instances.list._
  import cats.instances.int._
  val rs3: (Int, Iterable[Int]) = foldAndFilter3(1 to 10 toList)(n => n%2 == 0)((m:Int, _) => m+1)
```

but any generalization, on the one hand, leads to more readable, easy to write code, but on the other hand to less optimized in the particular case.

Comment: Can you provide some clarification on "effective parallelization can be achieved only on IndexedSeq to provide fast split operation"? Not sure what you mean here.

Comment: in order to split it effectively, you need to have `.liength` property and `.itemAt(idx)`. `Seq` doesn't have the `.length`. Look at the `.length` and `.apply`  implementation on the `List`. But `IndexedSeq` does have them. Look at the `length` and `apply` implementation on the `Vector`. So, `Seq` requires extra N operations to calculate the length.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of folding the filtered list of strings, fold the original list and accumulate into a tuple. That tuple would accumulate the lines from the original list that match the filter criterion into one component and the result of the original accumulation function into the other component.